# Using Integer in HashMaps

Tags: java

So I am trying to use HashMaps by specififying:

```
HashMap totalAtt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

But when I try to add two of the Integers, it gives me an error saying bad operand. How can I add the integers I retrieve from this HashMap without a compiler error or warning?

Edit: Replaced some code, no longer getting compiler error, rather warning of unchecked or unsafe operations

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getAttrib()
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> totalAtt = new HashMap();

    //Creates key values and initializes them to 0
    totalAtt.put("strength", 0);
    totalAtt.put("dexterity", 0);
    totalAtt.put("constitution", 0);
    totalAtt.put("intelligence", 0);
    totalAtt.put("wisdom", 0);
    totalAtt.put("charisma", 0);

    HashMap<String, Integer> sAtt;

    for(Sprite s: itemList)
    {
        //iterates through items and counts their attributes
        sAtt = s.getAttrib();

        totalAtt.put("strength", totalAtt.get("strength") + sAtt.get("strength"));
        totalAtt.put("dexterity", totalAtt.get("dexterity") + sAtt.get("dexterity"));
        totalAtt.put("constitution", totalAtt.get("constitution") + sAtt.get("constitution"));
        totalAtt.put("intelligence", totalAtt.get("intelligence") + sAtt.get("intelligence"));
        totalAtt.put("wisdom", totalAtt.get("wisdom") + sAtt.get("wisdom"));
        totalAtt.put("charisma", totalAtt.get("charisma") + sAtt.get("charisma"));
    }

    return totalAtt;
}
```

From Sprite class:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getAttrib()
{
    return attrib;
}
```

Comment: Please include more of your code that is involved in reproducing your error, along with the line that produces the error, and the error itself.  BTW, the raw `HashMap` reference variable is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Maybe just replace `HashMap totalAtt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` with `HashMap<String, Integer> totalAtt = new HashMap<>();`.

Comment: @rgettman Added more code, the current error is coming from:

     totalAtt.put("strength", totalAtt.get("strength") + sAtt.get("strength"));

Comment: @DavidS that removes the compiler error, but it's still giving me a compiler warning: "....uses unchecked or unsafe operations."

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
HashMap totalAtt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

to

```
HashMap<String, Integer> totalAtt = new HashMap<>();
```

and

```
HashMap sAtt
```

to

```
HashMap<String, Integer> sAtt
```

Comment: But if a comment is THE answer to the question it should be made an answer.

Comment: Besides that I added the second fix. ;-)

Comment: Okay I updated some code with the <String, Integer> in the proper place, still getting compiler error however

Comment: Which one do you get?

Comment: The <> at the end of

    new HashMap<>

worked! Thank you!